# How to get All Release Version Code and Relese Notes using Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-play-developer-api

i'm currently working with [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest) and [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client).

Is there any API to get All release data like Version Code, Release Note, etc from the first release? i'm using [Edits.tracks.releases](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks) but only get latest data in every track (internal, alpha, production)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you manage something out?

Comment: no there is no other way to get all version code using Google Play Developer API, only few latest version we get